# WSL 2 NAT issue preventing reverse shell on TryHackMe

Tags: linux, windows, networking, nat

I installed Ubuntu in WSL 2 on Windows 11. However, my WSL 2 instance is behind NAT, which is causing some problems. For example, I am unable to get a reverse shell on TryHackMe because my WSL 2 instance cannot listen on port 4444 with the `nc -lvnp` command. getting reverse shell works fine in Windows, but not in WSL 2. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> I installed Ubuntu in WSL 2 on Windows 11. However, my WSL 2 instance
> is behind NAT

WSL is not really a good Virtual Machine App subsitute - It was not designed for this.

To do what you want requires a Bridged Network connection.  You can do this with VMware Workstation, Virtual Box, or Hyper-V (called External).

You need to set up Ubuntu as a guest machine. I use VMware as it is the easiest and most flexible VM App in my view. I have a Hyper-V machine as well.

An unsanctioned method may allow you to set up a Bridged Network connection for WSL.  I am not recommending this, just noting that it might work.

[WSL Bridged Network](https://randombytes.substack.com/p/bridged-networking-under-wsl#:%7E:text=substituting%20the%20name%20of%20the,you%27ll%20have%20bridged%20networking.)

> Make sure WSL is currently shut down, and then add these lines to your
> .wslconfig file:
>
> [wsl2] networkingMode = bridged vmSwitch = Bridge